# How to add more than 3 GradientStop in RadialGradientBrush

Tags: c#, xaml, gradient

I have a `RadialGradientBrush` Tag applied to a `Path.Stroke` and the `Path.Data` is a Circle

```
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="2"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
```

But both Visual Studio designer and Application only show 2 RadientStop. I guess the gradient is too small but I change the Property `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` to a small number but I still don't get the result.

Comment: I didn't do xaml in a while but doesn't the offset have to be in range [0, 1]?

Comment: Sorry, I new to RadialGradientBrush, Everything I do is use property tab to set the Gradient. But today I need a Outerglow circle so I try to use 3 `Gradient Stop`s

Comment: So try to set `Offset` to `0`, `0.5` and `1`. This should do the trick.

Comment: But the Gradient Offset 0 is too small

Comment: @QuanVN as mentioned above - offset has range from 0 to 1. 0 means start of gradient vector, 1 means end of gradient vector. Offset 2 doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: @Evk I set 0 0.5 1 but 0 and 0.5 is hard to see

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding how radial gradient works (I mean - what those offsets really mean for it). I'd suggest you to read the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-paint-an-area-with-a-radial-gradient

Comment: Thank, I get it now, but I want to gradient Stroke, not Fill. So I quite confused MSDN gave me a ellipse but I only want to gradient the border(or Stroke).

Comment: Anyway , The change  the first `GradientStop.Offset` = 0.8 and second `GradientStop.Offset` = 0.9 solve my problem